# How to add image to product?

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, image-upload

I try to upload an image to my product at my fresh magento installation, but I can't find any way how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to enable Flash Player in your browser, you can install Magento Patch SUPEE-8788 too.

According to your Magento versions, you should download the exact version of patch file. Otherwise the patching is likely to fail. And of course, you should apply other patches too beforehead.

Release Note: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788

Download: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download1934

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I had to allow "flash" in my browser to make the buttons appear.

[image: upload button shows]

**Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced -> Content Settings -> Flash -> Allow:** *Add your host*

Comment: The magento devs should at least show an alert which tells us that Flash is blocked...